# Symfony2 get entity id in a twig template from a different field_row

Tags: forms, templates, variables, symfony, twig

Here is the code used to create the form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($city)
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('images', 'collection', array('type' => new ImageType())
            ->getForm();
```

City `images` property, is a collection of `Image` entity.

Here the definition of `ImageType`

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('path', new ImageFieldType());
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Entity\Image',));
    }

   public function getName() {
        return 'image';
    }
}
```

Here the code for my custom field type `ImageFieldType`:

```
class ImageFieldType extends AbstractType {
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array('path' => null);
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'field';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'imageField';
    }
}
```

In order to render the `ImageFieldType` I use the following block:

```
{% block imageField_widget %}
    {% if form.vars.value is not null %}
        <a href="{{ path('_cityManage') }}/CityID/ImageID">
        <img class="image_type" src="{{ asset('uploads/documents/' ~ form.vars.value) }}" />
        </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

How can I get the `city.id` and current `image.id` in this twig block? I've tried with `{{ id }}`, but this print something like `form_image_0_path`.

My goal is to have a link to the page `path('_cityManage')/city.id/image.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in cases like these (I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works):

In your case, in the controller I'd pass the variables you'd need when calling the render function:

```
return $this->render('view', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'city' => $currentCity,
    'image' => $currentImage
);
```

You can now use these variables in your template:

```
{{ city.id }}
{{ image.id }}
```

Again, I'm not sure if this is actually the best way to do it, but it works for me at the moment and I'm not aware of any other methods...